# What is the significance of _e("Some String", 'String')?

Tags: codex

I have seen this in lots of wordpress themes and using it for a while but don't know what is the significance of it. It seems it does the same work as echo something out.

Look for it in codex but failed to find anything about it. May be i have looked in wrong place.

So, my question is what does `_e("Some String", 'String');` means? And is it different from `echo "Some String";` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's for localisation/translation

[WPEngineer Has a great writeup on how it all works....](http://wpengineer.com/2237/whats-the-difference-between-__-_e-_x-and-_ex/)

Comment: Yup, saw it go by in my google reader last week, your question jogged my memory, figured I'd post it up for you!

Answer (score 1):

It's a [translation string](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

The first argument is the string to be translated. The second argument is the textdomain that defines the translation.